# Colocasia mojito leaves turning red and wilting

Tags: houseplants, plant-health

My colocasia mojito has a few leaves that are turning red and wilting the one in the close up picture is the worst.  I'm not sure if it's getting too much light or not enough. It's sitting on my dinning table about 6 feet away from south facing glass sliding doors. And the soil was moist to the touch so I didn't water it. I don't see any signs of pests. I live in Phoenix, AZ and keep my temp indoors at 74 - 75 degrees. No ac vents anywhere near this plant. Hope someone knows what I should do.[image]

Answer (score 1):

Hello I have one of these and I had the same problem, It was the soil. My plant wasn’t getting enough water in a regular soil mix with perlite I was using . I replanted with coco coir worm castings and just some really chunky orchid bark for air flow . I stopped losing leaves , mine too , were all turning reddish and drying up . When it is well watered the entire face of the plant will look upward with no droop to the leaf . This is how I am able to tell when to water also .[image]